# Need to apply loose coupling

Tags: java, function, loose-coupling

I have been using something like the following code

```
public void function()
{
OtherClass obj1 = new OtherClass();
OtherClass obj2 = new OtherClass();
}
```

How can i introduce **loose coupling** in this code?

Comment: You can use SPRING dependency injection.

Comment: @DineshxK pass the objects as parameters of the function

Comment: Loose coupling is about reducing dependencies. Your example is far too trivial to illustrate the concept.

Comment: @user2115021 Thanks. That seems a good way of applying loose coupling

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Pass the objects as parameters to the function, or better yet pass the interface that they implement. You would not **tie** the objects to the function in this way.

Event if this is more about dependency injection then loose coupling, it would not hurt making the change.

Comment: Yes. **Dependency injection** seems to be a good solution. Thanks

Comment: I used SPRING Dependency injection

Comment: @DineshxK i do not want to be mean, but adding Spring JUST for this is way to much.

Comment: Other features like SPRING's support for other frameworks also are helpful to my cause. And loose coupling is a critical requirement for my assignment. Sorry I couldn't explain my full problem in detail. Also am a newbie in IT industry. So plz dont mind my bad expression of the prob. Anyway thanks again

Answer (score 0):

Move obj1 and obj2 to member variables, and assign them externally from a different class.